# how to give the color to first column of the grid?

Tags: asp.net

i want to give color to the first coloumn as same as header of the grid.

this is the image of original grid which i want.
[image: this is the image of original grid which i want..]

this is the image of my which is displaying now

[image: this is the image of my which is displaying now..]

and this grid is created dynamically and all data are filld from server. so i want is to give color to only first coloumn ( not all coloumn , as shown in image)of grid at runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using simple CSS

```
table tr td:first-child
{
    background-color: #FACF7B;
}
```

**EDIT**: This rule will apply to ALL tables though. You can change it to only apply to certain tables, e.g.:

```
.myTable tr td:first-child /* all tables with class="myTable" */
{
    background-color: #FACF7B;
}

#myTable tr td:first-child /* tables with id="myTable" */
{
    background-color: #FACF7B;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add itemstyle to your first template field

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#FEFF01" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
 <ItemStyle BackColor="#FEFF01" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

EDIT:

see here is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewOrganizationShareFee" runat="server" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White">
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFC000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" Height="45px" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                         <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#FFFDFF" Font-Bold="true" />                      
                    <Columns>                  
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelOrganizationName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OrganizationID").ToString()=="0"?"n/a":Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>                           
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FEFF01" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                            <ItemStyle BackColor="#FEFF01" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fee Type">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Image ID="ImageDollor" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/dollor.png" Visible='<%#Eval("DojoEventPaymentType").ToString().ToLower()=="a"?true:false %>' />
                                 <asp:Image ID="ImagePercent" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/percent.png" Visible='<%#Eval("DojoEventPaymentType").ToString().ToLower()=="p"?true:false %>' />            </ItemTemplate><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: the itemstyle of your first template do exactly you wish it do not put over the whole columns

Comment: look my grid it , you got some idea.

Comment: you can also set this at databound event of grid

Comment: are you generating your column dynamically?? i don't find column in your grid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6646/discussion-between-neha-and-rohan)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
```

Comment: this is not supported in .net with vb.

Answer (score 1):

```
GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

post this after you bind grid data.ie after

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```